# Remove/avoid adding target link to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

This one may be simple for the jQuery/JavaScript gurus here, but I just can't find a solution for it around the web.

**Case**

I have a link at the bottom of a page that says `Back to Top`, the link is simply a target link like this:

```
<a href="#top" class="standard">Back to Top</a>
```

So when you click it, it jumps to the top of page. Simple.

**Problem**

When the target link is clicked, the id `#top` is added to the URL of the page, ie:

```
http://website.com/about-us/#top
```

**Question**

Is there a way to remove or avoid getting that id `#top` added to the URL of the page but retain the functionality of the page jumping to the top?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In either case (jQuery or vanilla JavaScript), you'll want to do the following:

- Select all anchor tags where `href` is set to `#top`
- Create a "jump" function which sets the page position to the top and ***returns `false`*** to prevent the default link behavior
- Bind the "jump" function to the `click` event of all of the nodes found

To jump you have several options. I've provided them (jQuery and JS specific) in the first example below.

**Using jQuery**

jQuery makes selecting and binding to a `click` event easy. Then you can jump to the top of the page using jQuery or straight JavaScript.

```
$('a[href="#top"]').click(function() {

   //
   // To jump, pick one...
   //

   // Vanilla JS Jump
   window.scroll(0,0)

   // Another Vanilla JS Jump
   window.scrollTo(0,0)

   // jQuery Jump
   $('html,body').scrollTop(0);

   // Fancy jQuery Animated Scrolling 
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

   //
   // ...then prevent the default behavior by returning false.
   //

   return false;

});
```

jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) provides options for animation duration and easing along with the ability to set a callback.

**Vanilla JavaScript**

You can also use Vanilla JS the whole way through... Querying and binding, however, become a bit more painful.

Modern browsers support [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which will allow you to grab all of the link elements just as you would with jQuery:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#top"]');
```

Then loop over the elements and bind the "jump":

```
for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  links[i].onclick = function() { window.scroll(); return false; };
};
```

If your target browser doesn't gift you with `querySelectorAll` you just loop through all of the anchor tags to find the ones linked to `#top`:

```
var links = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var l = links[i];
  if(l.getAttribute('href') === '#top') {
    l.onclick = function() { window.scroll(); return false; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah nice! This worked perfect. And the explanations are great, Thank You for expanding your answer.

Answer (score 2):

When handling anchor click events, always use `e.preventDefault();` On Click of Anchor element. When you don't need anchor element.

```
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
     return false;
});
```

You need to stop the tag a's default event to trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$('a.standard').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    });
});
```